# mysql where is null vs not exist

Tags: mysql

im trying to optimize mysql queries and i was wondering what is more efficient way to select rows by varchar(36) id that dont exist in a another table, which one is faster and is there a better way to do it that is not mentioned here? i can change the type from varchar(36) to bigint if needed

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
    WHERE (SELECT uuid FROM submitedTasks
               WHERE uuid = tasks.uuid) IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM tasks
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT uuid FROM submitedTasks
                WHERE submitedTasks.uuid = tasks.uuid)
```

Comment: Please get EXPLAIN SELECT... for any formulations you try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two queries will be almost exactly the same in terms of efficiency.
If you are looking for an actual optimization you may want to use the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` solution.

According to https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

> (...) The code that executes EXISTS predicate is about 30% less efficient than those that execute index_subquery and LEFT JOIN optimized to use the Not exists method.

In your case it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN submitedTasks ON submitedTasks.uuid = tasks.uuid 
WHERE submitedTasks.uuid IS NULL;
```

*Note - Make sure that you have index on `submitedTasks.uuid` column*.